# Flutter/Dart - Transparent Background until Future arrives?

Tags: flutter, dart, future, flutter-pageview

I'm trying to fetch a `PageView.Builder` which is built with data from the web. When I try to swipe to it from another page, I get a white background that seems to act as a placeholder until the web data from the `Future` arrives. What I'd like is for the original page to remain visible in the background until the page is built. But though I've tried everything I can think of, the background remains white until the `Future` arrives to fill the `PageView`. How can I get either a clear or at least a lowered opacity placeholder until it arrives?

I've used a CircularProgressIndicator as a placeholder but not only does it look bad (the swipe blows it up in all directions), but the background remains stubbornly opaque and white. I also tried a `Container` with a transparent color, but that merely overlays the white background of the Future. How can I get rid of the opaque white background which acts like a placeholder to the `Future`?

Here's the Future;

```
FutureBuilder<List<ReplyContent>> replyStage({String replyid}) {
  return FutureBuilder<List<ReplyContent>>(
    future: downloadReplyJSON(replyid),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        List<ReplyContent> replycrafts = snapshot.data;
        return StageBuilderVR(replycrafts, Globals.masterTitle);
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('${snapshot.error}');
      }
      return
        Container(
         color: Colors.transparent,
        );
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to take a different approach altogether and created a dummy Page that graphically mirrored the previous page with all the graphic elements of the previous page and none of the code. I used this dummy in place of the CircularProgressIndicator. It may not be the correct or best way, but it seems to work well. I'm quite pleased with the result.

```
FutureBuilder<List<ReplyContent>> replyStage({String replyid, String replytitle}) {
  return new FutureBuilder<List<ReplyContent>>(
    future: downloadReplyJSON(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        List<ReplyContent> replycrafts = snapshot.data;
        return StageBuilderVR(replycrafts, replytitle);
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('${snapshot.error}');
      }
      return DummyPage();
    },
  );
}
```